# Xcode storyboard won't refresh after making changes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, refresh

I have a project where recently the storyboards stopped refresh after I make a change. See the attached image:

[image]

In this situation I tried to move my Login button but only the selection frame moved. If I run the app I can see the changes and if I restart Xcode I can see it too.

Also I experienced this look some times:

[image]

Have anyone seen this Storyboard issue?

UPDATE!

I found this error message:

> file:///.../Login.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render
>   and update auto layout status for LoginViewController (dFL-RM-XIh):
>   dlopen(MyFramework.framework, 1): Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking   Referenced from:
>   MyFramework.framework   Reason: image not found

It likes it can't find the AFNetworking Pod inside my framework...

Comment: I think it is the bug of Xcode. What version are you using?

Comment: The latest, 8.2.1.

Comment: I got same issue some time ago. Just don't mind, or try to clean the project and derived data folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't work like this. I need to redesign this app. If I clean and remove derived data it helps until the first contraint modification.. :) Thanks though!

Comment: One more suggestion. Is your storyboard overloaded? How many viewcontrollers it contains?

Comment: I had the same issue, and I manually cleared out the derived data folder - no problems since :-)

Comment: Yeah it was really overloaded, but I created a new one with only a navigation controller and the Login controller. Didn't helped...

Comment: I think it's associated with Xcode overloading, something like this. Try to clear derived data, close all tabs in Xcode and open only that storyboard with which you are working.

Comment: I updated my question with an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message wasn't really helpful, but I found that if I remove @IBDesignable from my custom views located in my framework the issue has gone.